# Dock WPF ListBox to window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF MainWindow.xaml which contians a grid which has got two list boxes as follows:

```
<Window  blah blah >
<Grid>
    <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="DarkGray" CornerRadius="2" BorderThickness="1" >
        <Grid Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">ListBox 1</Label>
            <ListBox x:Name="lvTypes" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Visibility="Visible" Width="Auto"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="150" Background="#FFFFFFFF">
            </ListBox>

            <GridSplitter Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Width="5"></GridSplitter>

            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">ListBox 2</Label>
            <ListBox x:Name="lvObjects" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="150">
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

It looks as follows:

[image]

How can I get the right hand side of the grid to dock to the right hand side of the screen and for the two list boxes to be equal in the window?

Comment: When you said "screen", do you mean "window'?

Comment: yes I mean window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set column widths to * instead of Auto.

---

Your border sets `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` properties. These do nothing for you, as the outer `Grid` only has a single (default) row and ditto column. In fact, you don't need the outer `Grid` at all; you could just have your `Border` as the `Window` content.

Also consider changing this:

```
<RowDefinition Height="35"/>
```

to this:

```
<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
```